# Two issues with jquery ui sortable regarding layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-float, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two important issues to me that I need to resolve and I've been trying for months.., issues with sortable, I've created a fiddle to replicate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/tnLcg/134/

Drag F into B and you would see what I mean,

I don't want A, F, B, and C below B, then D and E

```
A F B
    C
D E
```

I want to see it the following the way.

```
A F B
C D E
```

It actually looks horrible with more than six elements as the structure of three inline is not kept due to the float left which is required by sortable on the sortable elements.

The other issue (less important) is how to vertical align these floated to the left divs when floated divs can't be aligned - to the bottom.

Here is an updated fiddle which covers both problems but adds a new one, extra height inside the ul, how to make it work without this height covering space.

http://jsfiddle.net/tnLcg/136/

Comment: I'll leave it as a comment for now because I don't have much time, it's a problem of float and clear, you need to clear:both the first element of the second row if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The ul has extra height because the `.block` class on your li's has a `min-height` and a `line-height` of 300px, which is taller than your tallest block. Try setting those attributes to 200px, which is the height of block E (the tallest):

```
.block {
    border: 1px dashed green;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    width:190px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-left:10px;
    min-height:200px; /*Changed to 200px*/
    line-height:200px; /*Changed to 200px*/
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Here's the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztu2z/